# TFS Upgrade to Azure DevOps - Is it possible to know what is the user for Search option

Tags: search, tfs, configuration, azure-devops, upgrade

I'm running the AzureDevOps installer as the upgrade mode.
Search is configured in actual TFS 2018 Update 3 installation but I don't remember using what user.

And when I try to run the installer above, during the configuration wizard I'm prompt that Search section has to be filled.
I tried with domain user that is used to access the machine but it's not right.

[image: Azure DevOps Server Configuration Wizard - Search section]

Is there a way to know what user is associated to that service?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username and password of Search tab which need you filled, is the **credentials** which need to provided to configured the Search feature.

At first, you must be a **TFS Admins** so that you have permission to operate it. As the doc: [Secure Search in Azure DevOps Server and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops#secure-search-in-azure-devops-server-and-tfs) and blog: [Introducing Search service authentication to make communications with TFS more secure](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/search-msrc-fix-for-tfs-2017-update-3-2/) defined:

> Upgrade to any of these releases requires one to provide a **new
>   user/password** while configuring Search (and during Search Service
>   setup in case of remote Search Service).

This means if you want to **upgrade**, the username/password need to be configured the **new** one. The format about these credentials configuration is:

> Username and password values should both be between 8 and 64
>   characters in length. While the password can be assigned any value,
>   the username can contain only alphanumeric and underscore characters.

In addition, for Search feature reconfigured, you need to specified the username as **AccountName** instead of **DOMAIN\AccountName**, or you will get the error.

Comment: What kind of access to TFS (if any) should this user account have? Also, what kind of Windows access (i.e. allow login as service, etc)?